# procedure is not working in start TRANSACTION(mysql)

Tags: mysql, procedure

I created and CALLed the procedure below, but it didn't work properly, so I posted it. which part is the problem??

I think the part where v_log_table goes in is not wrong. Because it worked well with that syntax in other procedures as well.

As a result of searching with test debug, it seems that the START TRANSACTION part does not work well...

```
    DECLARE v_done              INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_date_client_req   VARCHAR(8);
    DECLARE v_log_table         VARCHAR(6);
    DECLARE v_cnt               INT;
    DECLARE v_table_name        VARCHAR(18);

    DECLARE v_cursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.date_client_req, '%Y%m%d') as date_client_req
           , count(*) AS cnt
      FROM   ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_client_req, '%Y%m%d') AS date_client_req
               FROM   ata_mmt_tran
               WHERE  ata_id = p_ata_id
               AND    msg_status = '3'
               LIMIT  1000
            ) A
      GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(A.date_client_req, '%Y%m%d')
      LIMIT 5;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done = 1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;

    /*set transaction isolation level READ UNCOMMITTED;*/
    SET v_done=0;

    OPEN v_cursor;
    cursor_loop:LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor INTO v_date_client_req, v_cnt;
    IF v_done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE cursor_loop;
    END IF;

    IF v_date_client_req IS NULL THEN
        LEAVE cursor_loop;
    END IF;

    SET v_log_table = SUBSTRING(v_date_client_req,1,6);
    CALL bzt_ato_log_create(v_log_table);


    SET @sql_insert = CONCAT("INSERT IGNORE INTO ata_mmt_log_", v_log_table , "
            SELECT mt_pr
                , mt_refkey
                , priority
                , date_client_req
                , subject
                , content
                , callback
                , msg_status
                , recipient_num
                , date_mt_sent
                , date_rslt
                , date_mt_report
                , report_code
                , rs_id
                , country_code
                , msg_type
                , crypto_yn
                , ata_id
                , reg_date
                , sysdate()
                , sender_key
                , template_code
                , response_method
                , message_group_code
                , attachment_type
                , attachment_name
                , attachment_url
                , img_url
                , img_link
                , etc_text_1
                , etc_text_2
                , etc_text_3
                , etc_num_1
                , etc_num_2
                , etc_num_3
                , etc_date_1
            FROM  ata_mmt_tran
            WHERE ata_id = ?
            AND   msg_status = '3'
            AND   DATE_FORMAT(date_client_req, '%Y%m%d') = ?
            LIMIT 2000");

        SET @p_ata_id = p_ata_id;
        SET @v_date_client_req = v_date_client_req;

        START TRANSACTION;

        PREPARE stmt_insert FROM @sql_insert;
        EXECUTE stmt_insert USING @p_ata_id, @v_date_client_req;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_insert;

        SET @sql_insert = CONCAT("DELETE FROM ata_mmt_tran USING ata_mmt_tran A
        INNER JOIN ata_mmt_log_", v_log_table ," B
        ON A.mt_pr = B.mt_pr");

        PREPARE stmt_insert FROM @sql_insert;

        EXECUTE stmt_insert;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_insert;

        COMMIT;

        END LOOP cursor_loop;

    CLOSE v_cursor;

    SET v_done=0;
```

Comment: What is the incorrectness precisely?

Comment: i hoped ata_mmt_tran's data into ata_mmt_log_", v_log_table , " table but does not working insert